# Where to Create Object in .m File

Tags: objective-c, class, object, xcode5

I have a class and I need to make a global object of another class to use in the first class. So a MyClass1 object in MyClass2. I know the MyClass1 object = [MyClass1 new]; has to go in the MyClass2.m file, but where do I do this to make the MyClass1 object accessible to all the methods in the MyClass2.m? Any help would be highly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the object of `MyClass1` as a property in `MyClass2`, just declare in the MyClass2.h file the following:

`@property (nonatomic, strong) MyClass1 *object1;`

This you can initialize e.g. with the following code in `MyClass2.m`:

```
 - (id)init
 {
   self = [super init];
   if (self){
     self.object1 = [[MyClass1 alloc] init];
   }
 }
```

Later you can always call the methods of `object1` by calling (this works in *all* the methods of `MyClass2`):

`[self.object1 doSomething];`

Hope that helps!

Comment: I'm quite new to OOP in objective-C so I'm not sure where the init method is in the class.

Comment: Btw, the `init` method is the so-called _initializer_ of the class, in Java this would be called the _constructor_, it's a special method that creates an object of a class for your. In this case, it is used to create an object of class `MyClass1`